# How to manually upload a file with cypress?

Tags: javascript, jar, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-file-upload

I know that there is a plugin for doing this in cypress already. However using it with jar files just corrupts the file and therefore it is useless in my usecase. This is really weird because i tried it with every combination of encoding and it still does not work. Works perfectly fine with other filetypes however.

This is the code i am using (works except with jar files).

```js
 cy.fixture('test.jar', 'binary')
            .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
            .then(fileContent => {
                cy.get('[data-cy="dropzone"]')
                    .contains('Jar file')
                    .parent()
                    .find('div')
                    .attachFile({
                        fileContent,
                        filePath: 'test.jar',
                        mimeType: 'application/java-archive',
                        encoding: 'binary',
                        lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
                        subjectType: 'drag-n-drop',
                        force: true
                    });
            });
```

I know that you can perform post requests in cypress. Is it possible to perfom the file upload with it after clicking the dropzone element?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload/issues/346#issuecomment-972020346 ?

Comment: yes. that issue was even posted by me actually

Comment: Did you try setting mime type and encoding? If you did, you should probably add your attempts to your question.

Comment: updated the thread

Answer (score 2):

cypress-file-upload lacks explicit support for `.jar` extension, this is the current list of supported extensions

```js
const FILE_EXTENSION = Object.freeze({
  JSON: 'json',
  JS: 'js',
  COFFEE: 'coffee',
  HTML: 'html',
  TXT: 'txt',
  CSV: 'csv',
  PNG: 'png',
  JPG: 'jpg',
  JPEG: 'jpeg',
  GIF: 'gif',
  TIF: 'tif',
  TIFF: 'tiff',
  ZIP: 'zip',
  PDF: 'pdf',
  VCF: 'vcf',
  SVG: 'svg',
  XLS: 'xls',
  XLSX: 'xlsx',
  DOC: 'doc',
  DOCX: 'docx',
  MP3: 'mp3'
});
```

The default encoding used is therefore `utf8`. To explicitly pass in the encoding as an option, you need to use [raw mode](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload#working-with-raw-file-contents)

```js
cy.fixture('sample.jar', 'binary')
  .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
  .then(fileContent => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="dropzone"]').attachFile({
      fileContent,
      filePath: 'sample.jar',
      mimeType: 'application/java-archive',
      encoding: 'binary',
      lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
    },
    { 
      subjectType: 'drag-n-drop', 
      force: true
    });
  });
```

**Note** you need to try both subjectType values, as they trigger different events.

Here's the code that shows which shows which events are triggered with `force` option

```js
export const EVENTS_BY_SUBJECT_TYPE: Record<Required<HtmlSubjectType>, string[]> = {
  [HtmlSubjectType.input]: ['change'],
  /**
   * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent
   */
  [HtmlSubjectType.dragAndDrop]: ['dragstart', 'drag', 'dragenter', 'drop', 'dragleave', 'dragend'],
};
```

If you still get no action, you will need to manually trigger events, e.g chain `.trigger('change')` after `attachFile()`. Ideally you can figure out which events from the app source code.

---

The workaround given by abramenal is incorrect, this is the part of cypress-file-upload that handles the options parameter. If you pass fixture as a string, encoding is ignored

```js
function getFixtureInfo(fixtureInput) {

  // Normal mode
  // fixture name and options passed separately.
  if (typeof fixtureInput === 'string') {
    return {
      filePath: fixtureInput,
      encoding: '',
      mimeType: '',
      fileName: getFileName(fixtureInput)
    };
  }

  // Raw mode
  // If you pass an object, encoding can be specified
  return {
    filePath: fixtureInput.filePath,
    encoding: fixtureInput.encoding || '',
    mimeType: fixtureInput.mimeType || '',
    fileName: fixtureInput.fileName || getFileName(fixtureInput.filePath),
    fileContent: fixtureInput.fileContent,
    lastModified: fixtureInput.lastModified
  };
}
```

Comment: i tried using that code but it just passes the test without doing anything. i remember that i had to add the drag n drop option for it to even work but i cant find out where to put it exactly. adding it after last modified changed nothing. any ideas?

Comment: Looking at function `attachFile`, to change the subjectType to "drag-n-drop" you can just add the 2nd options parameter. I'll show it above. This option basically controls how the `input` element is found. If it's the default option of "input", then `cy.get('[data-cy="dropzone"]')` must yield the input itself, but if it's "drag-n-drop" then the input must be a child of `cy.get('[data-cy="dropzone"]')` and the input must have `type="file"` attribute. You can check all that in the browser.

Comment: However, if you're not getting any action after attaching the file, it sounds like you need to add the `force` option, which forces the events to fire (which causes the after-attach action to happen).

Comment: i edited my snippet. still same behaviour

Comment: Not, that's not the way - see the edit I made.

Comment: thank you very much but i am now getting the same error i had before. the file gets uploaded but when i try to use it or download it it gets corrupted. only happens with jar files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240984/discussion-between-vahn-toan-and-fody).